# How to get all pair of items from the list without using the itertools import combination

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list and I want all possible combinations of items of a list.

```
from itertools import combinations
l = [1,2,3]
for i in combinations(l,2):
    print(i) // (1, 2) (1,3) (2,3)
```

I want the same output but without using the itertools.
I tried:

```
l = [1,2,3]
for i in l:
    for j in l:
        print((i,j)) // (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)
```

How can I get the same output without using itertools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
for i in l:
    for j in l:
        if(j <= i):
            continue
        else:
            print(i, j)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find sample implementation of [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) in docs:

> Roughly equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def combinations(iterable, r):
>     # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
>     # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
>     pool = tuple(iterable)
>     n = len(pool)
>     if r > n:
>         return
>     indices = list(range(r))
>     yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
>     while True:
>         for i in reversed(range(r)):
>             if indices[i] != i + n - r:
>                 break
>         else:
>             return
>         indices[i] += 1
>         for j in range(i+1, r):
>             indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
>         yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a one liner just for efficiency:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]

([print(i, j) for i in l for j in l])
```